# All Elements in Div Not Appearing when Display is Set from None to Block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a popup that will appear when a user completes a certain task. This popup should contain a link saying Close (allowing them to close the popup) whenever it appears. My problem is that when the display is set from none to block, the link does not show up although it is inside the div.

```js
function closePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
}

function openPopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = 'This is the popup';
}
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 1.5% 0 1.5% 0;
  background-color: #afcb59;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="popup">
    <a href="#" onclick="closePopup()">Close</a>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="openPopup()">Open</a>
</body>
```

Comment: You're overwriting the content of div with `'This is the popup'` so you don't see the close button, you need to update the paragraph instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `innerHTML` to that paragraph not the `div`.

```js
function closePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
}

function openPopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'This is the popup';
}
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 1.5% 0 1.5% 0;
  background-color: #afcb59;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="popup">
    <a href="#" onclick="closePopup()">Close</a>
    <p id="text"></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="openPopup()">Open</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your script little bit, Added two more functionalities in closePopupfunction and same been done in openPopup function according, also have updated body tags in order to reflect the changes according to your needs.

```js
    function closePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("closepoup").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('closepoup').innerHTML = '  <a href="#" onclick="openPopup()">Open</a>';
}

function openPopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = '  This is the popup';
  document.getElementById('closepoup').innerHTML = '  <a href="#" onclick="closePopup()">Close</a>';     
}
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 1.5% 0 1.5% 0;
  background-color: #afcb59;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
 <body>
 <div id="closepoup">
  <a href="#" onclick="openPopup()">Open</a>
  </div>
  <div id="popup"></div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain *what* you changed and *why* you changed it to make your answer a better reference for future questioners.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function closePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("open_popup").style.display = "block";
}

function openPopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("open_popup").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('popup_text').innerHTML = 'This is the popup';
}
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 1.5% 0 1.5% 0;
  background-color: #afcb59;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="popup">
    <p id="popup_text"></p>
    <a href="#" onclick="closePopup()">Close</a>
  </div>
  <a id="open_popup" href="#" onclick="openPopup()">Open</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain *what* you changed and *why* you changed it to make your answer a better reference for future questioners.

Comment: I have just modified the functions if you can see in openPopup function I add one extra line that can hide the open tag after a click on it, and in the closePopup function, I add one extra line that can show open tag after a click on the close tag.